# What happens to Google Plus custom URL when you delete a Google account?

Tags: google-plus

So basically, when Google Plus custom URLs came out about 3 years ago, I signed up with my full name. Since then, I've received so much spam on my Gmail account that a few years back I created my own Google Apps account. I'm now using Google Plus on my Google Apps account but since custom URLs are unique, I can't get my full name since it's being used by my old account.

If I were to completely delete and clost my Gmail account, what happens to the custom URL? Is it locked forever to a non existent account or is it released after a set period of time?

EDIT: So I went ahead and deactivated the Google Plus page a few days ago. I'm hoping that by doing this, it will free up custom URL since it's now returning a 404. Fingers crossed Google releases my own name back to me since it's no longer attached to an active Google Plus page. That's what I'm hoping anyway. I'll report back if this works.

Comment: Have you tried editing the custom URL on the old profile to something else and then setting it on the new one?

Comment: Unfortunately, Google doesn't allow you to edit the custom URL to anything different, currently only the case sensitivity can be edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works! After deactivating my old account and waiting about 2-3 weeks, I was issued my old custom URL for my new account. So I just wanted to follow up with this comment in case someone else is wanting to do the same thing, I can verify that it works, it just takes some time for it to be purged through their system.

Comment: Thanks the feedback, I'm facing the same issue and will try your solution.

Comment: I was able to claim my former custom URL today! It took one month, but it worked.

Comment: It may not work anymore. I've been waiting since 5-10 May and still unavailable.

Comment: Hi @MichałPękała -- You are correct. It seems that last week sometimes, Google quietly began the process of removing Google Plus. Before, you would have your name and a + on the main Google page and clicking that link would take you to your Google Plus profile. Now, it's just your name with no link to click. Since Google Photos is now separate from Google Plus, it looks like they're going to split up more of Google Plus (perhaps a dedicated locations app?) or even kill off Google Plus entirely.

Comment: So I was just a couple weeks late. ;-)

Comment: And today Google sent me an e-mail that I'm eligible to get my "old" custom URL. It took almost 3 months.